# @EnableConfigurationProperties in Spring MVC

Tags: spring

I have a Spring application (not Spring Boot) with xml configuration.

To read properties from `application.yml` in Spring Boot I would use `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation to enable the functionality and then I would use `@ConfigurationProperties` on my class.

Is there somethis like this in pure Spring? Now it's done with `@Value` annotations

```java
@Component
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestProperties2 { 
    @Value("${myprop}")
    private String myProp;

    @Value("${commonprop}")
    private String commonprop;
}
```

Comment: Well, yeah, `@Value` annotations :P

Comment: Please see https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot if you want to use ```@ConfigurationProperties``` instead of ```@Value``` annotations.

Comment: In the title of your link it's mentionned Spring Boot but I have Spring that is not Boot

Comment: @Vitalii did you find anything?

Comment: As far as I remember, I found that it wasn't possible for Spring core (not boot). No idea if it is still the case now.